# GitHub action "Failure"

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to create my first Github action and likely missing something....

When I push my repo to Github and after click "Actions" in the Repo on Github it says Failure and it seems related to .github/workflows/test.yml.

**Error message:**

Error: .github#L1

every step must define a `uses` or `run` key

Anyone who can spot anything particular in my action related files?

The aim of my action is basically to run "npx ts-node index.ts" in my project/repo every 10 minutes.

**project/.github/workflows/test.yml**

```
name: Trigger Action on a CRON Schedule

on:
  schedule:
    # Runs "At 11:00 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday"
    - cron: "10 * * * *"

jobs:
  build:
    name: Trigger Script
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 16.x
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
          cache: "npm"
          cache-dependency-path: package-lock.json

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Run my action
        run: npx ts-node index.ts
```

**project/action.yml**

```
name: "Hunter"
author: "Bam"
description: "Hunting ..."

runs:
  using: "node16"
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you need the second step, but that is where your problem is as @VonC stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```yaml
      - name: Use Node.js 16.x
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
          cache: "npm"
          cache-dependency-path: package-lock.json
```

I do not see a `run:` or `uses:` in this step, which could be an issue.
See this [GitHub Actions workflow syntax example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_callsecrets).

`with:` is normally associated with `uses:`.

Comment: think the problem was that I forgot to add "uses: actions/setup-node@v3" after -name "use node..." it works now...

Comment: @Toothfairy Perfect, well done. All the examples I saw includes `uses:` before `with:`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
name: Trigger Action on a CRON Schedule

on:
  schedule:
    # Runs "At 11:00 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday"
    - cron: "10 * * * *"
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    name: Trigger Script
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.13.x
          cache: npm

      - name: Install
        run: npm ci

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Run myyy action
        run: npx ts-node index.ts
```